# SQL Server 2012 hangs at SqlRsConfigAction_install_ConfigNonRC_Cpu64

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation

For some reason SQL Server 2012 keeps hanging at SqlRsConfigAction_install_ConfigNonRC_Cpu64

There isn't any Windows installer running apart from the SQL Server setup.

**Update on Resolution**
Install SQL2012 without selecting Reporting Services

Comment: Are you sure you've killed any other installer background processes, not just checked that there's no other installer running in the foreground?

Comment: Windows installer is not running in services.msc. In the foreground, there's no other setup running apart from SQL

Comment: I don't think services.msc can help here. You need to check all processes in task manager ("processes" tab in the style of Windows 7 and earlier, "details" tab in the style of Windows 10 and likely 8 as well). You may want to check for details of what processes to kill in other posts where people have solved this sort of problem.

Comment: Can you add contents of [Errorlog file generated after failed installation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in the question

Comment: @Shanky please see the logs

Comment: @Deepz This is not helpful as it is incomplete log. I wanted to see the complete logs. Can you upload complete logs on Shared drive(like google,one drive) and post the link in question. Go to the folder logs and you would see complete set of logs produced please add it to shared drive and post the link here

Comment: Same issue here, but with SQL2016.  Hangs up, no activity, no other installers active.  Can't find any hidden popups.  Am not installing Reporting Services.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem after uninstalling Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x86) and (x64) and reinstall successfully sql express 2016.

But the best solution for avoiding this issue is **install sql server management studio and sql server express before installing visual studio**

Comment: Question is about SQL Server 2012.